# w3wp process using 100% cpu usage in sharepoint 2010 server

Tags: windows, sharepoint, w3wp

We have a w3wp process running on the SharePoint 2010 server(Windows 2008 R2) which is using 50-60% of the CPU usage and showing 100% CPU usage in the performance monitor. Following are some of the finding with this issue

1. This process id is not listing under "appcmd list wp" command and not on IIS worker process. But I can see this process on task manager (only when I check on all user process) and can't delete by end process button.
2. I tried to delete it by using taskkill command and it shows the result that the process terminated but the process  is still there in the task manager.
3. I have done IISREST and restarted SPADMIN service, but no use.
4. The process will stop only when I reboot the server.
5. This is not a regular issue on all days. This Process seeing in the server once or twice in a week.but not on a specific day.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you noticed any errors in the SharePoint logs while the CPU usage peaks? Are there any custom SharePoint solutions on your environment? Is memory usage rising with CPU usage, or staying steady?

Comment: 1. One sharepoint health analyser Error related to service is logged in the Event logs. But it was there on every hour even though this w3wp process is not there in the system. 2. There are custom webparts,workflows and timer jobs added to the site. 3. Memory usage is not rising up with the CPU usage. memory staying in the steady state of 10-20%.

Comment: I'd start by selectively disabling the custom timer jobs to see if one of them is the culprit.